# How to put cloud message on Code Listings fragment on LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, listingsutf8

I make a presentation 'beamer' with several slides of code using 'Code Listings', I would like to put cloud messages in some reserved words of the code for its explanation.

I have searched and I have not seen any questions or examples that make the messages about 'Code Listings' in the place that I indicate.

Similar to this:
[image]

This is possible?

regards

Comment: You can use an escape-character and then `\tikzmark` from the respective tikz library.

Comment: Hello @TeXnician, thanks for your answer, I tried your possible solution, but doesn't work because when I enter the block \[ ... \] inside  \begin{lstlisting} ... end {lstlisting}, it does not perform the arrows, but presents the script as it is in LaTeX.

Comment: Could you please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows what does not work? Please see also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351370/121799).

Comment: ... and if the code runs over more than one frame, also look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405347/121799).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
this is the first$\tikzmark{aux}$ line
This is the second line
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[rectangle callout, rounded corners, 
      callout absolute pointer={(pic cs:aux)}, 
      draw] at ([yshift=1cm]pic cs:aux){Note};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: For `beamer` which I skipped reading the question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, shapes.callouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{First frame}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape]
this is the first$\tikzmark{aux}$ line
This is the second line
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]

\node[rectangle callout, rounded corners, callout absolute pointer={(pic cs:aux)}, draw] at ([yshift=1cm]pic cs:aux){Note};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! But did you try the same thing in the document class beamer?

Comment: @marmot    I didn't read it the first time. It's the update working for you?

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi, it work, got it. How put several lines inner rectangle??, I try this: ... pic cs:aux){ Definition proposed $\linebreak$ second part};   , but doesn't work

Comment: @Alex: You can always put a table in the node, e.g. `\node[rectangle callout, rounded corners, callout absolute pointer={(pic cs:aux)}, draw] at ([yshift=1cm]pic cs:aux){\begin{tabular}{c}this is\\ some lengthy\\ explanation\end{tabular}};`.

Comment: @Alex: You have to define a certain `text width` in node options. The text will adjust to this width and you can also introduce line breaks with `\\`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123671/manual-automatic-line-breaks-and-text-alignment-in-tikz-nodes